# Having hard time figuring out a formula in Excel for trimming symbols and moving to a next row

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, office365

Before

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111-CZ20-00995 | NiceFoodsCo | Installment | 7789231;7652137 |

After

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111-CZ20-00995 | NiceFoodsCo | Installment | 7789231 |
| 11111-CZ20-00995 | NiceFoodsCo | Installment | 7652137 |

Basically I need it to remove the ';' and then move to next row with same data

Any advice would be appreciated, already tried VLookup, XLookup, Trim, Row, Substitute (and combination of all these)

Comment: This is a perfect case for a simple PowerQuery solution where you'll select the last column and split it on a semi-colon where you'd split the data into new rows instead of columns. Google: *"powerquery split to rows"*

Comment: Sadly power query does not work for some reason when I try to use it